# Camel: Claim Check + streaming splitter. Possible?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement where I will be receiving messages on rabbitmq. These messages will contain a document Id and an attachment name. Now I am using camel to consume from this endpoint. Now whenever I consume a message I want to download the attachment from a HTTP service and then split it. I want to use camel splitter for doing this. These files can potentially be over 1 GB in size so I want to split it while streaming them over HTTP.
   So my requirement is sort of a streaming claim check. Is this possible in camel?

Answer (score -1):

Got it working now. RecipientList to the rescue.

Comment: can you please share solution, as I am also facing similar issue.